# Why can the resolution be different in xrandr?

Tags: xrandr

Below is the output of `xrandr`. I expected that resolution would be the same in both lines of the output, where I replaced the actual resolution with `$thisPart` and `$andThisPart`, but the resolution is different. What is the difference between those resolutions? Why can they be different?

```
DP-0 connected $thisPart+4975+504 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm panning 2160x2160+3840+0 tracking 6000x2160+0+0 border 0/0/0/0
   $andThisPart     60.00*+ 144.00   119.98   109.95    99.93    59.94    50.00    23.98
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your screen is scaled, like with `--scale` or `--scale-from` options of `xrandr` (see `man xrandr` for usage), the resolution indicated after the word "connected" would be the resolution, which your desktop is scaled up or scaled down to, while the resolution marked with `*` will be the resolution actually rendered at your physical display.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Okay I get it, and is `--scale` the equivalent of `Change the size of text, apps, and other items: 150% (Recommended)` on Windows ?

Comment: @aaa What desktop environment are you using? Usually the DE provides its own tool to scale the screen. In GNOME, one of them is in Settings > Devices > Displays > Scale. It would be more fair to compare scaling in Windows with DWM to that than to scaling in X11 with RandR. Though, the perceived effect is _similar_.

Comment: I use multiple DE/WM and I struggle to find the same function as Windows to have readable text on the 4K screen but small text on 1080p screens. On Windows it resize all when you move the window from monitors, on Linux not so... I tried with `--scale` but it makes all blurry and messes with resolutions. And DE/WM only gives global scale (useless) + non fractional scale (useless++)

Comment: @aaa From your comment I understand that you want a solution to your issues with a 4K display. I have no experience with that. You should post a new question, describe your problem, system setup, and explain what you have tried and how it did not work. By posting your request in the comments here you limit significantly the number of those who may read it and help. The comments are only for discussion of how the post can be improved. If I answered your question about the xrdandr output, just press the checkmark next to my answer to let everyone know.

Comment: i will do that, thabks